# C# Delete node from BST - Am I on the right track?

Tags: c#, binary-search-tree

EDIT:

Right thanks for helping earlier, I have been using and the step into and step over and it looks to be working but the nodes are not being deleted and I'm not sure why.

I actually use 5 arguments for the BST but just using the one for testing purposes. It compares and finds if it has any children no problem. Just wont set it to null.

only testing nodes with 0 or 1 children.

main

```
Tree aTree = new Tree();
aTree.InsertNode("a");
aTree.InsertNode("s");
aTree.InsertNode("3");
aTree.InsertNode("1");
aTree.InsertNode("p");
aTree.PreorderTraversal();
aTree.RemoveNode("p");
aTree.RemoveNode("3");
aTree.PreorderTraversal();
Console.ReadKey();
```

My Delete Methods are:

Tree Node

```
    public void Remove(TreeNode root, TreeNode Delete) {
        if (Data == null) {

        }
        if (Delete.Data.CompareTo(root.Data) < 0) {
            root.nodeLeft.Remove(root.nodeLeft, Delete);
        }
        if (Delete.Data.CompareTo(root.Data) > 0) {
            root.nodeRight.Remove(root.nodeRight, Delete); 
        }
        if (Delete.Data == root.Data) {
            //No child nodes
            if (root.nodeLeft == null && root.nodeRight == null) {
                root = null;    
            }
            else if (root.nodeLeft == null)
            {
                TreeNode temp = root;
                root = root.nodeRight;
                root.nodeRight = null;
                temp = null;

            }
            //No right child
            else if (root.nodeRight == null)
            {
                TreeNode temp = root;
                root = root.nodeLeft;
                root.nodeLeft = null;
                temp = null;

            }
            //Has both child nodes
            else
            {
             TreeNode min = minvalue(root.nodeRight);
             root.Data = min.Data;
             root.nodeRight.Remove(root.nodeRight, min);
             }


        }

    }
```

Find Min

```
public TreeNode  minvalue(TreeNode node)
{
    TreeNode current = node;

    /* loop down to find the leftmost leaf */
    while (current.nodeLeft != null)
    {
        current = current.nodeLeft;
    }
    return current;
}
```

Tree

```
public void RemoveNode(string Nation)
{
TreeNode Delete = new TreeNode(Nation);
root.Remove(root, Delete);
}
```

Comment: Which line yields the error?

Comment: if (Delete.Data.CompareTo(root.Data) < 0)
        {
            root.nodeLeft = **Remove(root.nodeLeft, Delete);** //Void error here
        }
        if (Delete.Data.CompareTo(root.Data) > 0)
        {
            root.nodeRight = **Remove(root.nodeRight, Delete);** //void error here
        }

Answer (score 1):

`Remove` is of return type `void`, but you're trying to assign it to `root.nodeLeft` and `root.nodeRight`, causing your type conversion error.

Comment: I have change the code from root.nodeLeft = Remove(root.nodeLeft, Delete);  to root.nodeLeft.Remove(root, Delete); and vice visas for the right node and it has removed the errors so i will give this a spin and see how it goes. 

Thanks for the reply

Comment: Thanks the help and it basically works but the roots wont set to null for some reason.

Comment: Do you mean in the case of when there's no child nodes? That's the only time I can see where you're setting root to null.

Comment: I guess that would help but yes in the case of the no children as well.

Comment: It sets p for example to null at : `if (root.nodeLeft == null && root.nodeRight == null) { root = null; }`

then goes back to 
`if (Delete.Data.CompareTo(root.Data) < 0) 
{
 root.nodeLeft.Remove(root.nodeLeft, Delete);
}`

and reappears .

Comment: I cannot see any immediate problems with your code, but I can't currently run it through a debugger to verify.

Answer (score 0):

In general your Remove function needs to return the root of the sub-tree as the result, as in

```
 public void Remove(TreeNode root, TreeNode Delete) {
        if (Data == null) {
           return null;
        }
        if (Delete.Data.CompareTo(root.Data) < 0) {
            root.nodeLeft = (root.nodeLeft.Remove(root.nodeLeft, Delete));
            return root;
        }
        ... and so on.
```

Otherwise, since your nodes don't refer to their parents, there would be no way for the parent to know that the child node is gone, or that a new node is now at the root of the sub-tree.

Comment: If all else fails use a debugger ;)

Comment: - and start with tiny trees of one, two, three nodes, and work your way up form there.

Comment: All Done, thank you very much for your help. Now make it work it for a node that takes 5 arguments.